# Linux find part between two instances and write them to multiple outputs

Tags: linux, awk

I have a file that has PNG-image encodings inside of it. I would like to extract the PNG images from this file. Every PNG-image begins with "PNG" and ends with "IEND" word. The file itself contains more than a single PNG image (there are 279 matches).

How can I extract all these images in separate files?
I tried many `sed` and `awk` commands, but I was unable to create  multiple output files. Eg.

```
sed -n '/PNG/,/IEND/p' file1 > file2
```

How can I do this to make 279 PNG files?

Part of file is :

�PNG

...
IHDR...'...'...��Q5...  pHYs.....��...�IDATX���1
�0��W*B��Bp�P��x.A��qW���Ă�C3E��O�E�B������+��.��ո9EθMb���!/�]�
X��g�Y.5��o�ǁC+�����қ�Qh�O(�JqV��R�U�q���}��b�Z�E\Kw͙��xfn�$�xQ��&��7��)1�Lw�/�a{�W1�....IEND�B`�....�PNG

...
IHDR...&...$...�+��...gAMA..���a...sRGB.���...uPLTE�������
����������
������������������D�
��AGB����"'�ko����KO�6:�������������"""555�Zpwp���.."IDAT8����v� �a=1-����1����؃��.����om�b��窴'�?byU}�[�Ξ�Թ8m�^8�/����q��*�L(I!�����L�Bx(������[A n�3���5��u�]�S�&-��a]��f&a:B��h���1�G-9G�C��x(���Nk��JT���e-0%�8�4@*.�D��ִ1~���jV�̹ΐ��    ���������/:ԁ����r�������{���ّ���^�3۩<�)l)��Ie��R�cR�CR��p0gr»M....IEND�B`�..

This is the file I am working on: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1phPnEyGFWeHlXsGup9R35STf-NaGgFGR  (image also added to show a PNG file code, I want to extract that portions of file)

[image: This is the example of file]

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can best help you.

Comment: are the strings `PNG` and `IEND` written on separate lines, or are they the start and end of the image-string? The problem is that the encoding of the PNG could also contain the strings `PNG` and `IEND`

Answer (score 1):

This awk one-liner should help:

```
awk '/PNG/{y=1}y{print > "file"i+1}/IEND/{y=0;i++}' file
```

A test:

```
kent$  cat f
PNG
1
2
IEND
PNG
3
4
IEND
PNG
5
IEND

kent$  awk '/PNG/{y=1}y{print > "file"i+1}/IEND/{y=0;i++}' f

kent$  head file*
==> file1 <==
PNG
1
2
IEND

==> file2 <==
PNG
3
4
IEND

==> file3 <==
PNG
5
IEND
```

#### Note

add `close("file"i+1)` to `IEND` block: `/IEND/{close("file"i+1);y=0;i++}`  if you have err msg something like "too many files opened"

Comment: I think one of the main problems is that a `png` image could contain the words `PNG` or `IEND` itself.

Comment: from OP's description, this is not the case. otherwise, he/she won't use `/PNG/,/IEND/` range. but this should be clarified by OP @kvantour

Comment: As mentioned before, `print > "file"i+1` is UB per POSIX so YMMV.

Comment: Actually this is the file I am working on: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1phPnEyGFWeHlXsGup9R35STf-NaGgFGR

Comment: I edited question, I added link and added which instances of file I want to extract. There are 279 instances like this.